# zsh -- not seeming case sensitive?

Tags: macos, zsh

I was trying to copy some files with the same name, but different case, to the same directory.

See these steps:

```
~/tmp $ echo "First" > test
~/tmp $ echo "Second" > Test
~/tmp $ ls
test
~/tmp $ cat test
Second
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not from the Unix layer: it's from the filesystem. Probably it is OSX runs on HFS+. No other Unix does. So that's the difference. HFS+ is, by default, not case sensitive but is case preserving. You can re-fromat HFS+ as HFSX (case sensitive HFS+).

Comment: D'oh! Good point! Yep, I am on OS X on HFS+... I always forget that quirk.

Answer (score -1):

This has nothing to do with case sensitivity.  If you wanted both "First" and "Second" to show up in the file test, you should have written

echo "Second" >> test

(> writes to a file, whereas >> appends to a file)